# Converting Decimal In a Label to an Integer

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, type-conversion

Currently using VS2008, VB.NET, SQL.

I have a FormView from a Data Source that is getting some fields that are stored as Decimals in the SQL Database.

I am grabbing the field from the FormView as such:

```
Dim AvgTicketL As Label = CType(frmMerchantProfile.FindControl("F10Label"), Label)
```

I need to take this value, and convert it to an Integer, then send it along to an API.  I have the API Calls done, tested and working, but I'm getting an error as when it is getting this value, the API is returning "Must be an Integer" error.

What I have tried so far:

```
Dim AvgTicketL As Label = CType(frmMerchantProfile.FindControl("F10Label"), Label)  
Dim AvgTicket1 As Integer      
AvgTicket1 = Double.Parse(AvgTicket.Text)  
Do something with AvgTicket1
```

I have also attempted to Round the Value, then convert it and call it - no luck.

Checking the value of AvgTicket1 (Writing it out to a Label or Response.Write) shows "100", where the database value was 100.00.  But the API is still getting 100.00, apparently. Any other conversion method that I've attempted states errors that the Label cannot be converted to Integer.

What are some methods I can successfully convert this value to an integer from a label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some fooling around this is what I was able to do to get this to work...

I took some of what David had said, and then just made a simple adjustment - I don't know why I hadn't thought of it earlier!

```
Dim AvgTicketL As Label = CType(frmMerchantProfile.FindControl("F10Label"), Label)
Dim AvgTicketI As Integer = "-1"
```

I dimmed a second variable as an int, then

```
AvgTicketI = CInt(AvgTicketL.Text)
```

From there, I just called AvgTicketI as the variable to pass to the API.  Worked!

Thanks, David, for the guidance!

Answer (score 2):

The title of your question and the text of your question point to two different things.

Assuming you want to know how to safely convert the decimal value retrieved from the database, which is presumably the value of AvgTicketL, before calling your API you would do the following:

Create a variable of datatype Integer and use [System.Int32.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) to safely convert the decimal to an integer.  Then pass that variable.  (Code coming)

```
Dim testInt as Integer = -1

If System.Int32.TryParse(AvgTicketL.Text, testInt) Then
      ' Do something with testInt - call the API using the value
Else 
   ' code to execute if the parse fails.
   ' This could be whatever you need the code to do if the value of AvgTicketL.Text can't be properly parsed into an Int value.
End If
```

Comment: Thanks David!  This would work outside the If Else statement, correct?  For example, I have much more data to assemble prior to calling the API, so I would simply have to "Hold" this converted value to something, then call it later.  Also - Why the (-1) value when declaring the variable?

Comment: When attempting the way you've laid out the solution, I'm getting back a value of 0 - so I'm assuming the Parse failed.